# Access object value within accepts_nested_attributes_for form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have the following setup:

```
class Option < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :size_prices
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :size_prices
end

def new
  @option = Option.new
  @sizes = @customization.item.sizes 
  @sizes.each do |size|
    @option.size_prices.build({:size_id => size.id})
  end
end

<%= f.fields_for :size_prices do |price_form| %>
   I would like to do something like:
   <%= Size.find(price_form.size_id).name %>
   <%= price_form.text_field :amount %>
<% end %>
```

Is there any way to access the size_id's of each object with the form?  I would like to get the size objects name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, the .object on fields_for will give you the object it is building for

```
<%= f.fields_for :size_prices do |price_form| %>
  <%= price_form.object.size_id %>
  ...
```